# Display base64 string into webview as PDF

Tags: swift, pdf, webview

I have `base64` String that represents a `PDF`. 
I want to display it inside a Webview but I don't know how to do it well.

How should I process? Do I need to convert String to Data first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
if let decodeData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters) {
    yourWebView.loadData(decodeData, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
} // since you don't have url, only encoded String
```

## Swift 4.0

```
if let decodeData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
        yourWebView.load(decodeData, mimeType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
} // since you don't have url, only encoded String
```

Comment: When I pass my string to Data(base64Encoded: base64String) that return nil :(

Comment: it's objective-c

Comment: Check now @KevinSabbe

Comment: That work! I didn't know that I can use this method with empty string! Thank you very much @Sanjay you saved my day :)